# Mapping of a unit circle to a lune of a unit sphere quarter

Tags: differential-geometry, map-projections

Uniform $\lambda $ spaced circles of unit radius through origin are given by

$$ (x-\lambda)^2 +(y-\lambda)^2  =1$$

include a net of constant curved differential length rhombuses.

What is the equal area mapping of such unit circles onto a lune of unit sphere  spherical coordinates latitude/longitude

$$ 0<\theta<\pi/2,\; -\pi/2<\phi<\pi/2 ?\;$$

They both have an area equal to $ \pi 1^2.$

Thanks for any references / answer.